# Why doesn't luazip extract files when called from c++ application?

Tags: c++, lua, zip

I have a c++ application that interfaces with lua files. I have a lua file that extracts zip files, which works when I run it using SciTe or the Lua command line. But when I try to run it from a c++ application it doesn't seem to work.

```
 require "zip"

function ExtractZipFiles(zipFilename, destinationPath)
    zipFile, err = zip.open(zipFilename)

    -- iterate through each file insize the zip file
    for file in zipFile:files() do
        currentFile, err = zipFile:open(file.filename)
        currentFileContents = currentFile:read("*a") -- read entire contents of current file
        currentFile:close()
        hBinaryOutput = io.open(destinationPath .. file.filename, "wb")

        -- write current file inside zip to a file outside zip
        if(hBinaryOutput)then
            hBinaryOutput:write(currentFileContents)
            hBinaryOutput:close()
        end
    end

    zipFile:close()
end

-- Unit Test
ExtractZipFiles("SZProcessTests.zip", "Infections\\")
```

If I have Lua installed on the computer and double-click on the lua file it runs and the files are extracted as expected. But, it doesn't work if I try to run the lua file from C++ like this:

```
void CSZTestClientMessagesDlg::OnBtnExecute() 
{
    L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "ExtractZipFiles.lua");
    lua_close(L);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check for errors:

```
if (luaL_dofile(L, "ExtractZipFiles.lua"))
{
    std::cerr << "Lua error : " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
}
```

Apart from that, my guess is that Lua can't locate the zip module -- check your package paths settings, read about require in the [Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html).

In general, you need to check where the `zip` module is (`zip.lua`?) and make sure it's accessible during runtime (you can manually load it for example if all else fails).

Comment: Great response, that was very helpful.